How do you handle Big Datasets for training XGboost?
I had a dataset which has 530 classes and it was heavily imbalanced so as I am new to handling such large datasets I undersampled the top 10 majority classes and then concatinated it with other data and oversampled the dataset which came up to be 5,000,000 rows and as I used word2vec model which was trained on medical data, I had 902 features. The file was so big I had to save it to .parquet which was reduced it to 6GB.
Whenever I tried to use this file to train XGBoost even just for experiment I tried ml.g4dn.16xlarge it was throwing memory exceeded error.
2024-07-19T16:31:43.451Z

Free memory: 3264282624

Free memory: 3264282624
2024-07-19T16:31:43.451Z

Requested memory: 24778424320

Requested memory: 24778424320


So I did some digging on what can be done stumbled upon spark and dask.
Faced this particular error as well which was a nightmare for me did everything as per my understanding but didn't work out.
Failed to parse hyperparameter _tuning_objective_metric value validation:rmse to Json.
But in general wanted to know how experienced people handle these situations?

Dask can handle Datasets bigger than memory, but your question lacks some code example of what you are doing.

thanks for the reply @GuillaumeEB, I didn't add the code as I was just experimenting with it but I'll edit my post.

If the out of memory error is coming from Spark executor process, please check the maximum memory size configured for the Spark executor process. You may not be fully utilizing the total physical memory available on the instance.

I'll check this one.
